# Cannot Create Test Certificate in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, certificate, signing

When I go to my project properties page under the Signing tab and click "Create Test Certificate" I get the error "Object already exists. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8009000F)"

I've also opened past projects that I've created certificates for and tried to create new ones but I get the same error.

I had no problems creating certificates in the past. I am using Windows 7 and am running VS 2012 as administrator.

Anybody encounter this problem before?

John

Comment: Can anybody help?, I have searched everyone on google and cant find any solutions.

Comment: Update: I tried to create a certificate manually using makecert.exe but that also fails with the error "Can't create the key of the subject"

Answer (score 0):

this solved the issue for me HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid This key should ideally have the GUID of the machine without curly braces, so {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} becomes xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx